# Write To Object Variable SSIS/C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

Using a `Execute SQL Task` I query a table with two columns. Lets suppose the result set contains columns `Name` and `ProcessedFlag`. Where name is a string, and `ProcessFlag` is a `bit/boolean` data type, with a default of `0`.

The result set is loaded into a Object Variable named Data. Using a for each loop, I loop through each `name/ProcessedFlag` row, do what I need to with that information, and at the end of that loop, I want to set the `ProcessedFlag = 1` for that particular name.

The loop for many reasons runs multiple times (it's a loop within a loop), and I do not want it to process the same name again in the next run.

I have tried to use a script task to write to an object variable, but have been unsuccessful, my experience with C# is limited.

This example is just to set up a situation so I can explain the need. Mostly I'm looking for c# code that helps me write to an existing object variable while the package is running.

Thanks

Comment: When using a script task, add any variables you are going to write to to the ReadWrite variables list, then you can write to the variables in the script. See Configuring the Script Task in the Script Task Editor for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136097.aspx